# MySQL connection with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've got an database made in MySQL (through phpMyAdmin). it holds 2 "jokes". now i want to edit the jokes and update them in the database.

in this i work with 3 php scripts:

the script: edit.php (in here well be able to change the joke)

the script: connect.php (this will make the connection to the database)

the script: update.php (need to set the changes you just made in the datbase)

scripts so far:

**edit**

```
<?php

include ("connect.php");

if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    die('no id');
}

try
{
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM joke WHERE id = :id';
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    //koppelen van parameters in de query string
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', intval($_GET['id']), PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt->execute();
}

catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('Er is een probleem met het ophalen van joke: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

//ophalen van de gevonden rij
if ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $joketext = $row['joketext'];
    $jokeclou = $row['jokeclou'];
}

else {
    die('no row found');
}

echo <<<HTML
<form action="update.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{$id}">
    <h1>Joke database</h1>
    <p>
    <textarea name="joketext" placeholder="vertel je grap">$joketext</textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
    <textarea name="jokeclou" placeholder="wat is de clou ?">$jokeclou</textarea>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="Verzenden">
</form>
HTML;

?>
```

---

**connect**

```
<?php 
try { 
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=ijdb', 'root', ''); 
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
$pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"'); 
} 
catch (PDOException $e) 
{ 
echo 'Er is geen connectie mogelijk met de MySQL database. '.$e->getMessage(); 
exit; 
} 
echo "Een database connectie is succesvol opgezet"; 
?>
```

---

**update**

```
<?php
 try { 
 // de query is set in a string variabele
 $sql = 'UPDATE joke SET jokedate=”2013-04-25” WHERE id = 1'; 
 // next the query wil me executed and rows will change 
 // de method exec will return the rows if they are succesfully executed 
 $aantalrijenaangepast = $pdo→exec($sql); 
 } 
 catch (PDOException $e) { 
 echo "Er is een fout opgetreden bij de update: ".$e→getMessage(); 
 exit(); 
 } 
 echo $aantalrijenaangepast. " rij(en) aangepast"; 
 ?>
```

---

**there are a few things to keep in mind in this script:**

*the line: $sql = 'UPDATE joke SET jokedate=”2013-04-25” WHERE id = 1';* is the line thats incorrect at this point and it needs to update the information.

*the database content is set like:*
[image: databse content]

*to get to editting jokes make sure you add in 1 of the 2 id's behind the url to open a window with editting text boxes(?id=1)*

[image]

Comment: What's your actual problem?

Comment: phpmyadmin is not a database! It's merely a GUI for MySQL. MySQL is your database!

Comment: *I was reading this by thinking OP will tell me 2 jocks*. BTW as @deceze told. phpMyAdmin is just an GUI to interact with MySQL Database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have some fancy UTF8 characters in your update.php:

`”` should be `"`

`→` should be `->`

This can happen when you copy&paste code from websites.

Comment: This is what happens when you copy / paste code from websites that aren't encoding there text correctly.

Comment: @RPM this is not an encoding problem. This happens when the CMS of the website "pretifies" the source code on display.